# ASP.NET MVC define ckfinder baseurl dynamicly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ckfinder

Can I define upload and browse baseurl to ckfinder dynamicly in the following code? (when I m creating the ckfinder)

```
CKFinder.setupCKEditor(null, '@Url.Content("~/ckfinder/")');
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in ckeditor config file I added this.

```
baseurl="/uploads/images/" + System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
```